# Windows Subsystem for Linux: Error while installing MSSQL Server

Tags: sql-server, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I've just downloaded and installed Microsoft SQL Server into my WSL environment. Everything went smoothly as I ran `sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf setup`. I was prompted for the install version (eg Developer), install Language, and administrator password. When prompted to confirm, this happens:

```
    Enter the SQL Server system administrator password:
Confirm the SQL Server system administrator password:
Configuring SQL Server...

This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running.
The following diagnostic information is available:

       Reason: 0x00000003
      Message: fd != -1
   Stacktrace: 00007fda0c625833 00007fda0bfe76ba 00007fda095e682d
      Process: 397 - sqlservr
       Thread: 398
  Instance Id: 211a9fac-1061-47f2-8548-ab92a985561c
     Crash Id: e0ebf051-c561-4c3e-9162-e4fdf862b85f
  Build stamp: 33abe47c18f6a90a4d4f4d452a4549c8fd970e1c89a3d9170ba3b0292bc485a5
Multiple crashes have occurred
This program has encountered a fatal error and cannot continue running.
The following diagnostic information is available:

       Reason: 0x00000003
      Message: fd != -1
   Stacktrace: 00007fda0c625a0c 00007fda0bfe76ba 00007fda095e682d
      Process: 399 - sqlservr
       Thread: 401
  Instance Id: 211a9fac-1061-47f2-8548-ab92a985561c
     Crash Id: e0ebf051-c561-4c3e-9162-e4fdf862b85f
  Build stamp: 33abe47c18f6a90a4d4f4d452a4549c8fd970e1c89a3d9170ba3b0292bc485a5
*********** PANIC CORE DUMP GENERATION FAILED **********
Attempt to launch handle-crash.sh failed with error 0x0000000C
/opt/mssql/lib/mssql-conf/invokesqlservr.sh: line 15:   396 Aborted                 (core dumped) sudo -EH -u mssql /bin/bash -c "$CMDLINE"
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
Attempting to start the Microsoft SQL Server service failed.
```

So the configuration of the install fails (every time) and the service won't run.
Has anyone else encountered this problem? There is virtually nothing on Google about this, which is the reason I'm trying SO.

Comment: I just updated Windows to the Fall Creators Update version 1709 OS Build 16299, and I'm using a fresh install of WSL Ubuntu, and still no joy with installing SQL Server. I get an identical error to that shown above. I guess its not possible to install SQL Server on Linux on my machine, possibly due to hardware constraints.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, the Windows Subsystem for Linux for Windows 10 is not supported as an installation target for MSSQL-Server.

Source: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu